# My slider doesn't work correctly on iPad and Kindle Fire Linux mode

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net-mvc, slider

I have a problem in my e-commerce site called https://www.bencetupperware.com/ It was written with MVC.Net .
There is a slider at the top of the page. I checked the site on mozilla with response design mode.
It works correctly on the other platforms such as iphone 6/7/8, galaxy, but the problem is in the iPad and Kindle Fire Linux. Does anybody have any idea?

Comment: Hi, I've seen the problem and posted a couple of images to demonstrate it, but could you add some minimal code to your question which also demonstrates the problem - perhaps extract just one example which shows the images I've shown as it's difficult to advise otherwise.

Comment: I have looked at your site and it was fairly easy to see the problem so have posted an answer. I found it by using the dev tools in the Chrome browser on Windows and gradually decreasing the window size (also helped to set the animation duration to something large so things didn't change as I was looking at them). I'm not convinced the iPad isn't picking up the wrong media query, but even if it is setting the font-size to something smaller will make it work.

Comment: Hello Haworth,thank you for your interest,
I think there is a problem with resolution.
When I look at the iPad in responsive design mode, it should be 768x1024.
What exactly do I need to change? Can you help me?

Comment: Hi, have you tried making the font-size smaller where I've indicated in my answer that I had to make it smaller?

Comment: I have updated my answer to show exactly what you need to change to achieve the expected result. As you say there is a problem with the iPad I do not understand why this media size is being picked up on an iPad. Could you alter your site so I can try it on a real iPad? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATED: what to change:
Change this media query to have the smaller font size (it was 45px):

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 576px) and (max-width: 767px) {
    .slider-content-1 h3 {
        font-size: 16px;
    }
}
```

You need to look at the `font-size` settings in the css style file. Rather large fonts are being chosen for some smaller screen sizes. I altered the window size on Chrome on laptop and found that I needed to decrease the h3 font-size to get it to not be so large that it extended under the other boxes.

```
    .slider-content-1 h3 {
        font-size: 45px;
        font-family: "TupperPRO", cursive;
        color: #D3007E;
        margin: 0;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-style: normal;
    }

@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199px) {
    .slider-content-1 h3 {
        font-size: 70px;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
    .slider-content-1 h3 {
        font-size: 65px; /* THIS IS LARGE */
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .slider-content-1 h3 {
        font-size: 18px; /* THIS GETS OVERWRITTEN BY THE NEXT ONE FOR SOME DEVICES */
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 576px) and (max-width: 767px) {
    .slider-content-1 h3 {
        font-size: 45px;/* I NEEDED TO MAKE THIS SMALLER */
    }
}
```

This shows the site on a laptop (Chrome) and on a real iPad (Safari IOS 14) to show the problem.

[image]

[image]